# Running a basic web server

Tags: java, web

I have written a java class that implements basic web server.It gets the port number from console. This code is very basic, it returns what the client sends.Here are the code:

```
package p106;

import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class HttpMirror {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    try
    {
        int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);

        ServerSocket ss = new ServerSocket(port);

        for(;;)
        {
            Socket client = ss.accept();

            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream()));
            PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(client.getOutputStream());

            out.print("HTTP/1.0 200 en");
            out.print("Content-Type text/plain");

            String line;
            while( (line = in.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if(line.length() == 0)
                    break;
                out.print(line );

            }

            out.close();
            in.close();
            client.close();

        } // Tekrar döngüye gir ve bir sonraki bağlantıyı bekle. 
    }catch(Exception e)
    {
        System.err.println(e);
    }

}

}
```

I run this code and what must I write to my browser's address bar?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll still need to parse the incoming HTTP request with headers, body, etc and get the user content.

Answer (score 4):

Did you try localhost:*port number here*?  Or 127.0.0.1:*port number here*?

For example, if the port number is 8050, then the address would be **localhost:8050** or **127.0.0.1:8050**

Comment: I tried both, but I can not do it. My os is ubuntu 11.04. Mozilla Firefox is my browser.Port number "4444" is being given.

Answer (score 2):

You don't specify the command you use to start your java engine.

```
  int port = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
```

indicates that the port is passed on the command line.  So whatever port you pass there, you should put in your web browser.

Ex:

```
java HttpMirror 12345
http://localhost:12345
```

Comment: I am using Eclipse for running the java codes, and I gave port number "4444" as a argument in Run->Run Configurations->Arguments

Comment: And? Is this not working? Have you tried running in debug mode and set a breakpoint in your code to see if connecting triggers the breakpoint?

Answer (score 0):

First you need to check the port and then http://localhost:Portnumber for example http://localhost:8050